# Save uploaded files in subfolder depending on request

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I have a website, that lets user upload files. These files are attached to a node, which ID is part of the upload request. Since the same file might be attached to different nodes, Django will rename the file by adding a hash to the filename. Thus if a user downloads a previously uploaded file, it won't have the original filename.

Is it possible to create a subdirectory (named after the node ID) inside the media folder a file is uploaded? The closest solution I found was to change the System Storage of the FileField, but this is static for all files of that one model. Or is there another, better way to solve the problem with duplicate files?

Model:

```
class Attachment(models.Model):
    node = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=".")
```

View:

```
def file_upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = Attachment(file=request.FILES["file"], node_id=request.POST["node_id"])
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponse(instance.file.url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, take a look at the [documentation on `upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

You could do something like this, which includes the `node` id (defined as an integer in your model in the `upload_to` path:

```
def attachment_path_with_node(instance, filename):
    return "attachments/{}/{}".format(instance.node, filename)

class Attachment(models.Model):
    node = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=attachment_path_with_node)
```

Comment: What if you want to save to a folder like /2020/4? I mean to a folder like /{year}/{month}?

Answer (score 0):

Also path can be further customized like this:

```
document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

which would upload to: `MEDIA_ROOT/documents/2020/12/22/`.

See more at https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html